# Get value from sheet to another sheet in same spreadsheet by app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have one spreadsheet and this spreadsheet has a lot of sheet "first" , "second" , "third" , "last".

I'm working in sheet "last" need to import value some cells from sheets "first" , "second" , "third" to sheet "last".
the code want to be like that `function getdata(x,y)` the x is name of sheet, and the y is name box of sheet.
I use this method work but a lot of time not working give ERROR any another way work good.
this is the code :

```
function last(x,y) {
   const val = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(x+"!"+y).getValue();
   return val;
```

}

Comment: What cells do you want from each sheet?  And which sheet to you want the data and how do you want it organized?

Comment: What cells do you want from each sheet? example I need value from cell A1 in "first" sheet to "last" sheet,. which sheet to you want the data? "last" sheet. how do you want it organized? just I need import cell to another cell in another sheet: like in sheet "last" in cell "A3" need to get value from sheet "first" in cell "A1"

Comment: I don't understand what you want.  I'm voting to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can always define the sheet name of the sheet in the cell to pull data from sheet to sheet.  for my weekly time sheet, a cell with [='w (1)'!D17] grabs the D17 cell on the 'w (1)' sheet.

but I suspect you are are after more of a reference, not absolute sheets. Take a look at the `Sheetoffset(offset,cell)` function.  I use it to pull data from previous sheets

```
=@sheetoffset(2,e4)
```

will go back 2 sheets and get the data from cell E4.

Comment: arroba formulas aren't supported by Google Sheets and it hasn't a sheetoffset built-in function.